# JMS 1.1 durable subscription - can't set Client ID

Tags: java, jms, publish-subscribe

I am trying to setup a durable subscription with JMS 1.1 but I get in a Catch 22:

- if I don't set the clientID, I get a "clientID cannot be null" error...
- if I try to set it, I get:
  com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC3031: *A client ID cannot be set after connection has been used.
  The client ID of a connection can be set only once, and only before the connection is used.
  Set the client ID before using the connection.*

How do I solve this? How do I make the connection 'unused'?
Or - as the exception message suggests - how do I set the ID before I use the connection?

My code snippet:

```
public class BbsListener implements MessageListener {

...

public BbsListener(BbsListenerConfig config) {
    try {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup(config.getConnectionFactoryName());
        TopicConnection topicConnection = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        topicConnection.setClientID("ID");
        TopicSession topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup(config.getTopicName());
        topicSubscriber = topicSession.createDurableSubscriber(topic, "EAMPtestSubscriber");
        topicSubscriber.setMessageListener(this);
        topicConnection.start();
    }
    
...
```

Thank you

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Are you perhaps using some kind of connection pool? If so, maybe the connection in the pool has already been used when you get it and that's why it's complaining about this.

Comment: BTW,  I cut/pasted your code into a JUnit test and it worked fine with ActiveMQ Artemis. There must be something in your environment that's triggering this issue or perhaps a bug with the IBM JMS client implementation.

Comment: @JustinBertram Yes, looking at the config (see below) there is a pool-name attribute defined but being a total rookie in this topic I am not sure how to remove the connection from the pool. Can you please help with this?
<connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedTopicConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="WMQConnectionFactory" enabled="true" tracking="false" pool-name="WMQConnectionFactory">

Comment: Generally speaking, when you invoke `createConnection()` on a pooled connection factory it provides a connection from the pool rather than actually creating a physical connection as would be done with a normal connection factory. So, to "remove" a connection from the pool you simply call `createConnection()` as you're already doing. When you call `close()` on the connection it puts the connection back into the pool.

Comment: It looks like your app is running on a Java EE application server. If that's the case you'll need to be careful about what kind of connection factory you use and where you invoke `setMessageListener()`. First, an "outbound" connection factory is meant to be used for *sending* messages (hence the name "outbound"). This is part of JCA. Second, you can't call `setMessageListener()` in an EJB as that's not allowed by spec. I recommend you just use a normal JMS connection factory rather than a pooled one from the application server.

Comment: Justin, thanks, indeed what messed it up is manually calling the setMessageListener() which is not allowed in the EJB container. Post your reply as an official aswer if you will and I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks for following up! I posted my previous comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your app is running on a Java EE application server. If that's the case you'll need to be careful about what kind of connection factory you use and where you invoke `setMessageListener()`. First, an "outbound" connection factory is meant to be used for sending messages (hence the name "outbound"). This is part of JCA. Second, you can't call `setMessageListener()` in an EJB as that's not allowed by spec. I recommend you just use a normal JMS connection factory rather than a pooled one from the application server.